# Was Panacea affected by Glory Girl's aura?

Tags: worm

Mild spoilers ahead!

In Worm, Panacea falls in love with her step-sister, Glory Girl. Part of Glory Girl's power is an emotional aura that, unless she turns it off, makes people around her view her with adoration if GG is in a good mood or awe/fear if she isn't. I *think* at some point Panacea claims to be immune to this aura, though I don't have a source quote handy.

I've seen a number of fan discussions (and fan fiction) which seem to take it for granted or explicitly claim that Panacea is *not* in fact immune, and only loves Glory Girl because she went through puberty constantly being hammered with Glory Girl's emotional aura, effectively brainwashing her.

Is there any evidence in the original material or a statement directly from Wildbow supporting this theory, or is it merely very widespread fanon?

Comment: I haven't reread Worm in a while, but I followed it pretty religiously back when it was being written, and I don't think there's anything in canon (nor do I recall anything from WoG) that suggests Panacea was in love with Glory Girl because of GG's powers.

Comment: Our [general policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) on spoilers in titles seems to be __don't__. I have no idea what you're talking about, but if this is indeed a spoiler, please try obscuring it enough that unsuspecting visitors don't get spoiled. Note that this doesn't mean inserting things like [SPOILERZ!] to the title or the body, but rather choosing appropriate wording. You can also use the spoiler tag: `>!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been [mentioned by Wildbow](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/worm-quotes-and-wog-repository.294448/page-12#post-20937115) at least once. The consensus is that persistent exposure during puberty caused her to develop that way, and Wildbow's comment suggests that was the intent. She only claims she's immune because her aura pushes her to love her but she already does.